# jQuery colorbox loading very abruptly

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I have a screen which is loaded inside the jQuery colorbox, it works fine but the problem is the way it loads does not look smooth. Is there any issue with the following code? Or is there any setting which I can't find?

```
$.fn.colorbox({
    iframe : true,
    width : '90%',
    height : '90%',
    scrolling : false,
    className: 'team-regedit-popup',
    href : url + "?" + params+"&projectId=" + projectId,
    overlayClose : false,
    onClosed : function() {
        $(parent.document.getElementById('cboxClose')).show();
        var sortId = $('.sortButton.sort_sel').data('sortid');
        var searchText = $('#searchText').val();
        projectRegistration.displayTeamTable(sortId, searchText);
        F.unlock_scroll(self);
    }
});
```

I have tried with `fastIframe: false` but didn't helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `transition` flag in the [docs](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/), it has three values, default is `elastic`, try with `none` or `fade`.

```
$.fn.colorbox({
    iframe : true,
    width : '90%',
    height : '90%',
    scrolling : false,
    transition : none,
    className: 'team-regedit-popup',
    href : url + "?" + params+"&projectId=" + projectId,
    overlayClose : false,
    onClosed : function() {
        $(parent.document.getElementById('cboxClose')).show();
        var sortId = $('.sortButton.sort_sel').data('sortid');
        var searchText = $('#searchText').val();
        projectRegistration.displayTeamTable(sortId, searchText);
        F.unlock_scroll(self);
    }
});
```

Hope it will help.